# Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... [Fatal Error] aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, aapt2

No errors when `flutter doctor` command was executed. I tried with updating Gradle with the latest version 6.4 and setting at env variable path as well, in the dist folder as well it is showing correctly.

### gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4-bin.zip
```

### android/app/build.gradle

```
- compileSdkVersion 28
- targetSdkVersion 28
```

### android/build.gradle

google() is added to allprojects and buildscript.repositories

```
I tried all approaches mentioned in similar kind of queries in StackOverflow and other platforms but of no use, I am totally stuck here.

how to resolve this error?
```

On `flutter run` command following ERROR is what I get:

> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>
> ```
> [Fatal Error] aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.**
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
>    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
>      Required by:
>          project :app
>       > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
>          > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom
>             > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> BUILD FAILED in 6m 22s
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       401.6s (!)
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
> ```

Comment: Were you able to fix this error ?

Comment: unfortunately not :( @K Pradeep Kumar Reddy

Comment: I'm also getting similar error in my flutter project  [Fatal Error] checker-qual-2.5.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.